# How to get selected value of SELECT OPTION

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

i am having a problem with my code, i have two SELECT, the first one is "drop_drop" and the second one is "salidhan_ini", which will change the option of the "salidhan_ini" every time the "drop_drop" is change, it will hold the value of the "salidhan_ini" from the database using php, but my code is not working.

INDEX.PHP

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#drop_drop').on('change', function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:"process.php",
            data:{keyname:$('#drop_drop option:selected').val()},
            success: function(simbag){
                $("#salidhan_ini").html(simbag);
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dropdown1">
<select name="taskOption" id="drop_drop">
  <option value="1">What</option>
  <option value="2">When</option>
  <option value="3">Where</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="dropdown2">
<select id="salidhan_ini">

</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

process.php

```
<?php
    $id_man = $_POSt['taskOption'];
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sample_sample");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sample_hatak where id = $id_man");
    if(!$result){
        echo 'Error: '. mysql_error();
    }else{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<option value=". $row['FirstName'] .">". $row['LastName'] ."</option>";
        }
    }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

what i want to achive is everytime the "drop_drop" is change, the value of selected option from "drop_drop" will be past into "process.php" and then it hold all the data that has the corresponding id which is the value of selected option of "drop_drop" and then it will return all as the option for the "salidhan_ini".
thnks for helping!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you give us a more detailed error description? What exactly is not working and what is happening instead?

Comment: Why are you including two different copies of jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to populate 2nd select as follows-

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#drop_drop').on('change', function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:"process.php",
            data:{keyname:$('#drop_drop option:selected').val()},
            success: function(simbag){
                $.each(simbag, function(val, text) {
                $("#salidhan_ini").append( $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text) )
              });
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Also include only one version of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help!
i found my problem,the problem is in `process.php`

```
<?php
    $id_man = $_POSt['taskOption'];
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sample_sample");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sample_hatak where id = $id_man");
    if(!$result){
        echo 'Error: '. mysql_error();
    }else{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<option value=". $row['FirstName'] .">". $row['LastName'] ."</option>";
        }
    }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

the problem is "`$POSt`" so i change it to, "`$_POST`",

and this `echo "<option value=". $row['FirstName'] .">". $row['LastName']`
the `FirstName` and `LastName` is not part of my attribute in my database, 
because it is `firstname` and `lastName`.

thanks!